# Replace evolution with Kontact?

Tags: kmail

Can I remove evolution from gnome to replace it with Kontact?

Meaning:

- Make all apps use kmail as Mailer.
- Make Openoffice use kaddressbook
- get korganizer to show up in the indiciator calendar
- start akonadi at gnome start
- make tracker index kontact documents

can this be done?

Comment: Do you still have the problem. Have you found how to solved the problem or considered accepting an answer that solves your problem (if any)?

Comment: sadly yes the problem remains, now after evolution is officially dropped as PIM in 12.04 there is still the need for integration of a PIM and the only one I know that's offering more than mail and contacts is the Kontact suite of KDE (though buggy) ...

Answer (score 2):

To make applications use Kmail instead of Evolution when handling `mailto:` links and etc., go to
`System -> Preferences -> Preferred Applications` and change the `Mail Reader` setting to Kmail.

I doubt some of the other changes you are asking about are possible.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, what consequences it has to remove evolution as a package (since it is quite integrated in ubuntu-desktop), however, you can additionally install Kontact.

You could also just install kubuntu-desktop, which brings you the whole KDE desktop on (K)ubuntu. You can then decide during login if you want to use the Gnome desktop or the KDE desktop.

Comment: Evolution itself is not so integrated with ubuntu-desktop since Lucid and the list of dependencies is really short, even shorter in Maverick.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. For my purposes the Kontact components are vasly superior to their evolution counterparts. It's just hard to get them integrated i feel. Can't figure it out ...

Comment: Well.. kmail is part of the KDE suite. Hence, it is integrated into KDE. Maybe you are better off using Kubuntu instead. You can still run all the Gnome apps there.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to sync between an existing data set then you might like to try opensync as a transfer medium.

The indicator calendar is getting massive attention for the Natty cycle, so it's likely it'll have strong bindings and all it requires is a kde developer to tie akonadi to it.

The open office integration is a simple code change, but it isn't simple to implement.

Over all it would be easier to wait for the dbus work in evolution to complete so your Kontact client data is simply the same backend that evolution uses and thus that evolution is giving everyone else.

Comment: thx! that's interesting hints. Could you explain or link some source for that dbus stuff? Do you intend to say I could use both, kontact and evolution, on the same set of data like having to different frontends but the same emails, contact, dates, notes and stuff?

Comment: http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/01/d-bus-metadata-api-for-linux-mail-clients.ars

Comment: thx very much! I read through but there seem to be no progress at the moment. Anyway - there's hope :-)!

Comment: BTW: I tried to get going with opensync but it's somewhere in beetween versions, no gui and no docs that I understand ... Waiting seems to be the name of the game ...